# modulo n generic counter

Tags: generics, vhdl, counter, modulo

I am required to design a modulo "n" counter with generic parameters. I am having trouble fixing the length of the std_logic_vector which will hold the output.  Firstly, I get errors regarding the use of airthmetic operators on numeric types. And secondly, I am not allowed to use a dynamic expression in the range specification of the vector. Here is my code so far:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;  
use IEEE.math_real.all;

entity counter_mod is
  generic(n: integer range 1 to integer'right);
  port(clk,reset,load:in std_logic;
  data_in:in std_logic_vector(ceil(log2(1.0*n))-1 downto 0);
  q:out std_logic_vector(ceil(log2(1.0*n))-1 downto 0));
end counter_mod;

architecture behavioral of counter_mod is
begin
  process(clk,reset,load)
  variable count:std_logic_vector(ceil(log2(1.0*n))-1 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
  begin
      if(reset='1') then
          count:=(others=>'0');
      else if(load='1') then
          count:=data_in;
      else if(clk'event and clk='1') then
          if(conv_integer(count)=n-1) then
            count:=0;
          else
            count:=count+1;
          end if;
      end if;
      end if;
      end if;
      q<=count;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Must change `ceil(log2(1.0*n))` to `natural(ceil(log2(real(n))))`, to address
  the type mismatches
- Must change `count := 0` to `count := (others => '0')`, since it is not
  possible to assign `0` directly to `std_logic_vector`.
- May change `integer range 1 to integer'right` to `positive`, since use of the
  `standard` package type states the intention clearly
- May change range in variable declaration to `data_in'range`, since use of the
  VHDL attribute states the intention clearly
- May change `if(conv_integer(count)=n-1) then` to `if (count = n-1) then`,
  since the `conv_integer` is not required when using
  `ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all`
- May change `if(...) then` to `if ... then`, since `()` are not required in
  `if` because `if` is a statement and not a function
- May change `clk'event and clk = '1'` to `rising_edge(clk)`, since use of the
  `std_logic_1164` package function states the intention clearly
- May change the `else if` to use of `elsif` for a clearer and less verbose
  style

The code can then be updated to:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.math_real.all;

entity counter_mod is
  generic(n : positive);
  port(clk, reset, load : in  std_logic;
       data_in          : in  std_logic_vector(natural(ceil(log2(real(n))))-1 downto 0);
       q                : out std_logic_vector(natural(ceil(log2(real(n))))-1 downto 0));
end counter_mod;

architecture behavioral of counter_mod is
begin
  process(clk, reset, load)
    variable count : std_logic_vector(data_in'range) := (others => '0');
  begin
    if reset = '1' then
      count := (others => '0');
    elsif load = '1' then
      count := data_in;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if count = n-1 then
        count := (others => '0');
      else
        count := count+1;
      end if;
    end if;
    q <= count;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Consider changing `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` to `ieee.numeric_std.all`, since
the `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` is not a standard package, so the place in the
`ieee` library is misleading.  It requires change in inner `if` to:

```
if to_integer(unsigned(count)) = n-1 then
  count := (others => '0');
else
  count := std_logic_vector(unsigned(count)+1);
end if;
```